# Java running out of memory for big variable?

Tags: java, oop, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a massive file of approximately 32000 lines. I am making some operations over its content in Java, so I created a smaller, minified file of it to test my program. It works fine, but when I use the actual file (the larger one, of 32000 lines), it explodes, saying that:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at translator.MainLinkedHashMap.createLinkedHashMapFromString(MainLinkedHashMap.java:100)
    at translator.MainLinkedHashMap.main(MainLinkedHashMap.java:25)
```

Please note the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is > 1.

I´ve been debugging and I saw that the LinkedHashMap, where I am storing the lines of the file, has 30400 lines instead of 32000 in the debugger.

Is this stating that Java ran out of memory? (The file is not so big itself, 2M, but there is a lot of lines.)

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Here is the code:

```
private static LinkedHashMap<String, String> createLinkedHashMapFromString(String rawString) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        String [] values = rawString.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = values[i].trim();
        }

        String [] pair = null;
        for (String value : values) {
            pair = value.split("=");
            resultMap.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }
        return resultMap;
    }
```

Comment: no, it clearly states that your array is not long enough, its size probably 0 or 1, so index 1 (you remember that array indexes starts with 0) is out of the bounds

Comment: Code please... What does your `createLinkedHashMapFromString()` method do?

Comment: @Lashane I clearly said it´s a LinkedHashMap, not an array...

Comment: Well there's your problem: one of your "pair" values does not have an "=" sign in it.

Comment: If you would ran out of memory you would get `OutOfMemoryError` :)

Comment: @Antoniossss Wow! Really?

Comment: Yeah really trust me!! If you would have known that, than you would not ask if u are running here out of memory

Comment: @Antoniossss Not every memory problem throws an OutOfMemoryError

Comment: That is probably something I did not discovered yet. Anyway, in your case it would - all in all it is not the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the content of you file but the exception ist 100% thrown in this block

```
   for (String value : values) {
        pair = value.split("=");
        resultMap.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
```

in line  `resultMap.put(pair[0], pair[1]);`

simply saying, the result of `String#spit` is just 1 element length(remember that the first element of array is indexed as 0) and that is why you are getting your error. I bet that not all "lines" in your files are in the form you are expect them to be.

Comment: So what are you looking for here anyway? You got your answer - not a memory fault, only file content is not as you expected.

Comment: @stackpepe Clearly you don't know that already, because you thought it was running out of memory.

Comment: @Boann please, don't put comments that doesn't help the answer. Is that something relevant in a question asked 5 days ago? I don't think so